How to proxy fetch requests in chrome extensions?
I see the solution to this nowhere, and yet have the question:
How to proxy fetch requests in chrome extensions?
I have this code:
async makeRequest() {
    const postData = {
      // ..payload
    };

    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(postData);
    const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/endpoint/";
    try {
      // HERE I WANT TO USE PROXY!

      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json", 
        },
        body: jsonData,
      });

      return response;

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during fetch:", error);
      return false;
    }
  }

My app is a webscrapping chrome extension, therefore the usage of proxies for my webscrapping purposes is fundamental.
Also saw that we can use the proxies manifest permission, but the problem that I run into using that implementation is that configures the Proxy for the WHOLE COMPUTER, and i only want it for the chrome extension requests.
Any solution?
Thanks!
